# How to set textfield when the parameter list more than one

Tags: jasper-reports

I have put input list of name kem from my parameter. It is `kem 1`, `kem 2`, `kem 3`. I have create ***`$x{in,pd_id,Kem}`*** as a parameter but the result just show `kem 1` from three kem. What I want is when I put list name of kem, the data will display all of the data. That is `kem 1`, `kem 2`, `kem 3`.
This is my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testspace" language="javascript" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="kem" class="java.util.Collection">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select
PD_ID,
PD_NAME
from wf_proc_def where $X{IN,PD_ID,kem}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PD_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="PD_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="118" y="24" width="334" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[ ("1".equals($P{kem})) ? "kem1"
:("2".equals($P{kem})) ? "kem2"
:("3".equals($P{kem})) ? "kem3"
:("4".equals($P{kem})) ? "kem4"
:("5".equals($P{kem})) ? "kem5"
:null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of jrxml file (with parameters, query and `textField`)?

Comment: im sorry so much late to reply,i have put my code at above.Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something wrong with your parameter `kem` which must contain the list of values. You should initialize this parameter.

This is working sample (it works with iReport's sample database):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <parameter name="cities" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Dallas", "Lyon", "Paris"})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID, CITY FROM ADDRESS WHERE $X{IN,CITY,cities}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cities}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result generated in `iReport` preview function:
[image: Result generated via iReport preview]

***UPDATE***:

***How to resolve values by keys with help of [google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library***

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <import value="com.google.common.collect.*"/>
    <import value="com.google.common.base.*"/>
    <parameter name="cities" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="citiesMap" class="java.util.Map">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>().put("1", "Dallas").put("2", "Lyon").put("3", "Paris").build()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    ...
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cities}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="185" y="12" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Maps.filterKeys($P{citiesMap}, Predicates.in($P{cities})).values()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    ...
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:
[image]

Comment: i have try your sample but there are error.Actually, i want parameter is a input name="ID" and not "cities". When i put the list of ID, it will show the desc cities in report.For example id 1 ='Dalas', 2= Paris and 3= Lycon.How to do that?

Comment: In my sample the `ID` this is PK of `address` object, not the `city` object. The sample is working - what error do you have? By the way, for this sample the report's language must be set to `Java`.

Comment: i have try but the result is not what i want. What i want is case when id 1 ='Dalas', 2= Paris and 3= Lycon

Comment: I don't understand what is your requirements. Is the query in my sample ok? You can change the query, for example: `<![CDATA[SELECT id, name FROM city WHERE $X{IN,id,ids}]]>`, where `ids` - parameter, the list of ids. What is the problem?

Comment: when i put list id 1,2,3.Then the result just show list 1,2,3. What i want is  when i put the parameter id 1,2,3.the result will show Dalas,Paris,Lycon

Comment: Do you want  to write "getter" to show the city name by id in one `textField`? The ids were set as parameter, right?

Comment: yes sir. For example i want the parameter id=1 and the result on report show of id is 'dalas'.

Comment: @Amin I've just add another sample - with guava

Comment: @Amin I don't understand your question. I posted the working sample - all you need is to copy-paste this code to your report. You need to add guava to the classpath (iReport: Tools - Options - Classpath - Add JAR). The report's language should be set as `Java`

Comment: i have try with empty datasource.can you set the just one parametern with sql?. When i put the id of parameter. it will convert to description.

Comment: Yes, I can. You can type the string `2` in `iReport` dialog "Parameter prompt" (preview function) for the `cities` parameter. Or you can type two values: `1, 2`

Comment: i have try and it was success but how to get rid of [] in list. i just want to show dalas, lyon, paris

Comment: You should use this expressions: `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cities}.toString().replace("]", "").replace("[", "")]]></textFieldExpression>` and `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Maps.filterKeys($P{citiesMap}, Predicates.in($P{cities})).values().toString().replace("]","").replace("[","")]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: i have found new problem.Can i ask you question?.